# Pip not working due to old version of pip existing

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, python3, pip

```
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/docker/requirements.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am trying to install a repo build and keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

`PIP` is a Python package manager tool, it is like the **top-level package administrator**, it surely cannot install itself.

It seems your Python version is 3.5, you can upgrade your PIP by using

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```